# PCManFM cut and paste not working

Tags: 18.04, pcmanfm

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and general love it except for the fact that the file browsers suck.  My latest attempt at file browser satisfaction is to use PCManFM.  While I generally like PCManFM it has issues with cutting and pasting from directories.
I can open two PCmanFM windows and drag and drop between them.  What I cannot do is copy from one directory, navigate to a different directory, and then paste into that location.  Nothing happens.
I can go up one level and I see that there is a paste option under edit but this also does nothing.

I can cut and paste in PCManFM if I am not in detailed lists view but that sort of defeats the who point of an open-source software if I can't make it work like I want.

Furthermore, sometime PCmanFM shows directories as empty but if I shift to a compact list view, or use Thunar, I can see the contents of the directories.

Why can I not just cut and paste in PCManFM?  What are the issues with the detailed list view?

PCmanFM was installed using sudo apt-get install pcmanfm

I can confirm that I am the owner of all directories and files in these folders.

Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I just tested this on a Lubuntu 18.04 LTS system and it worked for me.  I am aware however that across a directory system there can be many varied *file-systems* (my system here has a 160gb hdd but has >20TB of *file-systems* mounted on my 36gb /) which complicate reason. Are all your *fs* local with the same RW permissions? and you have write permissions to them?  You provided no specifics as to the file, or it's location where you 'copy', nor where you later tried to 'paste' to, if they are the same file-system, or you have the same or different permissions to those directories.

Comment: In PCManFM I have noticed if you are using "detailed list view" sometimes "paste" won't show up in the context menu, especially if the screen is full. Try "icon view", then copy/cut a file, put the cursor on the white space between icons, and right-click for the context menu. If you don't get a "paste" option, something else is wrong.

Comment: This is Ubuntu to which you've added pcmanfm? How did you do so? If it was the command line, what was the exact command?

Comment: I am definitely using PCman with a detailed list (it was the one file browser that maintained detailed lists across directories).  I use the information at this link to do the installation.  https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/pcmanfm

Comment: I can confirm that PCmanFM works as expected with the icon view.  Part of the reason I abandoned Nautilus and Thunar is that they would not maintain detailed list views across all directories and had to be set one directory at at time.  Installation method?  Hard to remember but I am sure it was sudo apt-get install pcmanfm.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm I have 2 machines, one with Ubuntu + pcmanfm installed with sudo apt-get intall pcmanfm, the other with lxde installed (which includes pcmanfm) on top of ubuntu. Is 18.04 in both occurence.

While the second one has ctrl+c or +x/+c working as expected, the first one does not (ie, the shortcut do not work and Paste is greyed out).

edit after some additional tests:
(1) I can confirm that the problem was shwing in detailed view and basically gone after switching to icons/list view, whichever.

(2) I found here : https://sourceforge.net/p/pcmanfm/bugs/1059/
an indication about using gnome-tweaks to turn off icons on desktop.
It was already off on my machine, and switching on/off did not help.
Then I played a bit with the Desk options while I was there, switching them on/off.
At this time they are all switches off AND PcmanFM is now back working as it should, including detailed mode view.

Go figure.